# Localhost And IIS Error

Tags: localhost

For no apparent reason, my localhost started showing a blank screen when I visit any of the websites that are hosted on there.

After a bit of research I found that it may be the IIS (Internet Information Services).

So I checked the `IIS Management Console` box under `Web Management Tools` in `Windows Features`, and the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager is now showing up in my `Administrative Tools`.

However, localhost is still showing a blank screen.

I then must have done something wrong in `Common HTTP Features`, because now when I visit my site I see a `IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoJFz.png)

Does anyone know the correct boxes to check to get localhost back up and running? Or know of the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have the following IIS features installed and then try accessing your websites at http://localhost/{application}

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great visual Mohsin. I actually completely unchecked `Internet Information Services`, restarted my computer, and everything went back to normal again.

Comment: Completely unchecked means you uninstalled the IIS feature? I am not clear about this!

Comment: Not clear on it myself. I was just so wound up about it not working that I unchecked it to see what would happen, and everything worked fine after system reboot.

Comment: Weird! So if you check your current IIS installed feature settings do you see all boxes unchecked under it? Or may be you unchecked all the boxes but restarted the server without applying or saving